# laravel authentication without using email field

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. By default, Laravel uses the email field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a username method on your LoginController. However I want to authenticate users based on their registration number. How do I achieve this.

Comment: define the `username` method on the `LoginController` as you stated from the documentation, return the name of the field, what ever the registration number is held in, from that method

Comment: https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-auth-login-email-username-one-field/ please check this link